# Is String.Equals(string1.Substring(0, x), string2) better than string1.StartsWith(string2)?

Tags: c#, .net

I am using string comparisons to test URL paths using `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase`.

MSDN gives the following string comparison advice [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465121.aspx#the_details_of_string_comparison), but does not clarify **WHY**:

MSDN Example (half-way down the above page):

```
public static bool IsFileURI(string path) 
{
   path.StartsWith("FILE:", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
   return true;
}
```

MSDN Advice:

"However, the preceding example uses the String.StartsWith(String, StringComparison) method to test for equality. Because the purpose of the comparison is to test for equality instead of ordering the strings, a better alternative is to call the Equals method, as shown in the following example."

```
public static bool IsFileURI(string path)
{
   if (path.Length < 5) return false;

   return String.Equals(path.Substring(0, 5), "FILE:", 
                    StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
}
```

**QUESTION: Why does MSDN suggest the second example is better?**

Discussion points:

1. Clearly the `return true;` in the first example is a bug and should be `return path.StartsWith(...);`. **We can safely ignore this as a bug as the VB code is correct.**
2. Creation of a substring prior to comparing for equality would appear to only use another memory resource than just calling String.StartsWith().
3. The Length < 5 test is a nice short-circuit, however it could be used with the prior code just the same.
4. The second example could be construed as clearer code, but I am concerned with performance. The creation of the substring seems unnecessary.

Comment: Based on the fact that the `StartsWith` sample function makes no sense, I'm going to go with the idea that the sample originally used a different function (like `CompareTo`), and somebody changed the sample haphazardly without paying attention to the context.

Comment: I find the 'startswith' to be much, much clearer at expressing your intent.

Comment: @Gabe Can you opine on the general question then? Using StartsWith seems preferable to me. Creating a Substring for comparison seems likely to perform less well.

Comment: @I82Much - I agree, the code using `StartsWith` is much cleaner in my opinion (once the bug in it is fixed).  I think the possbilities here are that 1) Microsoft is saying that `StartsWith` is completely broken and should never be used, or that 2) someone made careless modifications to an old/pre-existing article, changing it in such a way that it no longer makes sense.

Comment: @I82Much I tend to agree. Which is why the advice seems odd. Ideas?

Comment: @aroth Perhaps someone with Reflector could lend insight. I prefer `StartsWith` but don't want to disregard specific advice.

Comment: You pulled these snippets out of context... I don't know the full details about this but this is in a section where it's discussing culture-sensitivity.  This recommendation seems to be only in this particular case and not the general case.  You need to make that clear so everyone here knows that...

Comment: @JeffMercado Yes, it's a long article discussing many aspects of comparison. I provided a link to the article. I don't see anything out of context in my excerpt; if there is, it is not intended. I appreciate the sharp eyes as that may be where the answer lies. I am very identically comparing file paths using `OrdinalIgnoreCase`.

Comment: @KevinR: The `StartsWith` method is generally preferable, as they both end up making calls to the same internal function `InternalCompareStringOrdinalIgnoreCase`. The only real difference is that `Equals` has an optimized case where both strings are all ASCII.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the `StartsWith` method using dotPeek, it eventually calls an internal comparison function that compares the entire string, and returns a boolean result based on the return value of that comparison:

```
return TextInfo.CompareOrdinalIgnoreCaseEx(this, 0, value, 0, value.Length, value.Length) == 0;
```

`String.Equals` calls:

```
return TextInfo.CompareOrdinalIgnoreCase(this, value) == 0;
```

`CompareOrdinalIgnoreCase` calls a private method, which dotPeek doesn't show, but my hunch is that the overload called by `StartsWith` traverses the entire string while the overload called by `Equals` stops as soon as equality can be determined.

If performance is a concern, try measuring both with values that will be typical for your application.

---

Out of curiousity, I tried measuring the two, and it does seem that `Equals` is noticeably faster.  When I run the code below using a release build, `Equals` is nearly twice as fast as `StartsWith`:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var url = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8867710/is-string-equalsstring1-substring0-x-string2-better-than-string1-startswit";
            var count = 10000000;
            var http = false;

            Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                http = url.StartsWith("http:", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            }

            sw.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine("StartsWith: {0} ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

            sw.Restart();

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                http = string.Equals(url.Substring(0, 5), "http:", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            }

            sw.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine("Equals: {0} ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that! I can't imagine why `StartsWith` would continue to traverse the entire string beyond the length of its argument. Similarly, `Equals` can't determine equality until both strings are completely traversed, unless an inequality is found sooner.

Comment: @KevinR: No, the `StartsWith` function internally only traverses the length of the prefix.

Comment: @adrift: The reason Equals is faster is most likely because the strings you're comparing are all ASCII (which has an optimized case in `String.Equals` but not `StartsWith`). If you use a single non-ASCII character in the first 5 characters, you should see that speed advantage disappear.

Comment: @adrift: Indeed, your performance test shows `Equals` takes about half the time. I even modified it to use a non-constant comparison string (replaced "http:") and the results were very similar. Gabe seems to have nailed the reason WHY, and because I am comparing URLs (i.e., ASCII), it appears `Equals` is the way to go even though the `Substring` looks as if it would be slower. MUCH THANKS!

Comment: @KevinR: On my computer, the `Substring` starts to make the `Equals` method slower after about 16 characters.

Comment: @adrift: I replaced `"http:"` with `"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8867710/is-st"` (first 48 characters) and now `StartsWith` is significantly faster. Perhaps it depends on how long it takes to create the longer substring. I may rethink my solution based upon the expected average URL length I am comparing! (Edit: Gabe posted nearly the same thing) Thanks to both.

Comment: @Gabe, good call, I think you got it with the handling of ASCII strings.

Comment: Another good point to think about is that x.Substring copies the characters from the original string into a new string instance. This means that garbage collection will be taking longer, and that should be included in the test to get an accurate image of what truly the cost difference is.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is found immediately below the code example you provided in under the `Ordinal String Operations` heading.

> Strings in the .NET Framework can contain embedded null characters.
>   One of the clearest differences between ordinal and culture-sensitive
>   comparison (including comparisons that use the invariant culture)
>   concerns the handling of embedded null characters in a string. These
>   characters are ignored when you use the String.Compare and
>   String.Equals methods to perform culture-sensitive comparisons
>   (including comparisons that use the invariant culture). As a result,
>   in culture-sensitive comparisons, strings that contain embedded null
>   characters can be considered equal to strings that do not.
>
> **Important**
>
> Although string comparison methods disregard embedded null
>   characters, string search methods such as String.Contains,
>   String.EndsWith, String.IndexOf, String.LastIndexOf, and
>   String.StartsWith do not.

Meaning that `String.StartsWith` and `String.Equals` that use ordinal comparisons will return different results. That is, the whole point of using ordinal comparisons was to prevent people on Turkish systems circumventing security concerns (where `"f" != "F"` when ignoring case). Meaning someone could still circumvent security concerns by passing a file URI that looked like `"FIL\0E:"` if the test used `String.StartsWith`

Comment: No, I think you misread both paragraphs: "...these characters [nulls] are ignored when you use the...methods to perform CULTURE-SENSITIVE comparisons". Using `StringComparison.Ordinal` is not a culture sensitive comparison. Also, "...string search methods such as...StartsWith DO NOT [disregard null characters]". The issue with nulls occurs with `Compare` and `Equals`, but NOT `StartsWith`. Neither disregards nulls when using `Ordinal` comparisons. That's my take and testing on my end appears to support it. Appreciate you pointing out the importance of `Ordinal` compares and any other thoughts.

Comment: @KevinR Looks like you're right. I originally read the important note before the rest, which might have been the source of my confusion.

Comment: Easy to get confused which is why I asked for more sharp eyes on this. I think adrift and Gabe enlightened the correct details. Best.